# Messages in the Cloud with multiple Apple IDs

Tags: ios, icloud, apple-id, messages-in-icloud

**Background**

I use the same main Apple ID for iCloud across all the iOS devices (a couple iPhones and a couple iPads) in my household. However, for one of the iPhones, I use a different Apple ID for Messages/iMessage. This is on my wife's iPhone; she uses her own Apple ID for Messages so that she has her own set of messages and conversations on her phone.

So, on her iPhone, the iCloud info shown at the very top of the main Settings.app view shows my Apple ID credentials. However, down in the Messages settings under the *Send & Receive* view, her own Apple ID is listed.

**Question**

If I turn on the new Messages in the Cloud feature — the one that's new in iOS 11.4 — how will this work with the setup I've described above?

My fear is that after I've turned on Messages in the Cloud on my iPhone — and all my messages sync up to my iCloud account — when I turn on the Messages in the Cloud feature on her iPhone, all my messages will sync down to her phone. Or, probably just as bad, possibly all her conversations and my conversations would be merged together in some Frankenstein sorta way.

I'd rather not have to try this in anger in order to find out how it'll work. Either of the scenarios above would be hard to recover. So, I'm hoping someone already knows what'll happen.

Thanks!

Comment: You should **NEVER** share Apple ID's between two or more people. There is no scenario where this would be good. You can share purchases through family sharing and it will always create more problems then solutions such as this one.  I would suggest keeping each person's Apple ID completely separate then turn on Family Sharing. Many people mistakenly do this.

Comment: @Josh: my wife and I have been sharing the same Apple ID for just about a decade on our iOS devices. Thanks for your words of caution, but it's been OK for us so far. I'd really (really!) like to move to Family Sharing. Just as soon as we can share our iCloud Photo Library via Family Sharing, I'll be there. For me, this is the last major feature missing from Family Sharing. And until then, Family Sharing is a no go for us.

Comment: Glad to hear.  [You should be able to use iCloud Photo Sharing for that](https://www.imore.com/how-use-family-sharing-photos-icloud). Anyway, good luck!

Comment: @Josh: I'm aware of the Family Sharing album. It's not good enough. This is for a couple reasons: *1.* The photos shared via the Family Sharing album are not full resolution. *2.* Photos have to be manually added to the Family Sharing album. **All** our photos are communal. That means we'd have to continuously manually add all our photos to the album. Nope, the Family Sharing album doesn't cut it for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot turn on Messages in the Cloud on an iOS device wherein the Apple ID for Messages differs from the main iCloud Apple ID. iOS will notice that the Apple IDs do not match and will deny the request to turn on Messages in the Cloud. It will show this error message:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Don't turn on iCloud Messages for either device.

You can continue to use iCloud Backup and include your Messages, if you want them backed-up. If not, leave that off, too.

As previously mentioned, sharing Apple ID's nowadays will start causing more problems as Apple and developers start using individual iCloud accounts for more individual use.

Perhaps looking into other photo sharing options to get what you need, until Apple does something, is the better short-term approach.